# Why am I not being notified of comments

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, comment-replies

I am not being notified of comments on the stackexchange inbox anymore.For example,this question: [Evaluating an improper integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220752/evaluating-an-improper-integral)

Did's comment in response to my comment(made in response to Did's answer) was not notified to me.

Can anyone please fix the problem?Thanks.

Comment: Some useful links explaining more about comments and notifications can be found in [comment-replies tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are the owner of the question, but not the owner of the answers. As such the comments on answers do not automatically appear in your inbox.

Furthermore, your username was not pinged by did, and automatic ping does not work if there are more than one user involved (except the owner, that is). Once Emmad Kareem left a comment it ensured that you won't be pinged unless explicitly done so in the comment.

Comment: I did not know that. So you say I should have added @Chris to my comment for Chris to be notified of it? Hmmm... tricky business! :-) Thanks for clearing this out.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks for the info.